# image from url - storing as invalid format php

Tags: php, image, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I am using jquery-gdrive plugin for choosing image, file, docs from google drive, it returning the url. from the url i am storing the image to my local disk if i try to open the image it showing invalid image, same thing for dropbox chooser also how to solve this issue?

here is my google drive url - gdrive://DSC_0031.jpg/0Bx-Ck9De1dkOeExfT1o2SEZWNDQ
here is my dropbox chooser url - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruqu1bfrs371ntj/spokeless-bike.jpg?dl=0

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="imageUpload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="gdrive_file" type="text" name="imageToUpload"> <a href="#" id="gdrive_file_selector">Select file</a><br/>

        <div class="submitBtn">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-gdrive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $().gdrive('init', {
                'devkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'appid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            });

            $('#gdrive_file').gdrive('set', {
                'trigger': 'gdrive_file_selector', 
                'header': 'Select a file', 
                'filter': ''
            });
            $('#gdrive_folder').gdrive('set', {
                'trigger': 'gdrive_folder_selector', 
                'header': 'Select a folder', 
                'filter': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

```
<?php
$image = $_POST['imageToUpload'];
$s = basename($image);

file_put_contents("uploads/$s", file_get_contents($image));
?>
```

here is my dropbox chooser code

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="6s50p5csnfjties"></script>
  <!-- Replace data-app-key with yours -->    

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#db-chooser").on('DbxChooserSuccess',function(event)
{ 
   alert("Here's the chosen file: " + event.originalEvent.files[0].link);
     console.log(event.originalEvent.files[0].link);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Magnus, i thing i logged in, in dropbox let me check once again, so what i have to do for gdrive url, is their any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: It won't matter if you login in your browser, that won't give the web server access. The web server is clueless, as it should be, about what the browser can access. You need to look in to using both dropbox and google drives API's and authenticate using Oauth.

Comment: ok thank you, let me try

Answer (score 3):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruqu1bfrs371ntj/spokeless-bike.jpg?dl=0 is not a link to an image. It's a link to a web page that has an image on it. There are two ways to get the kind of link you want:

1. Try https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruqu1bfrs371ntj/spokeless-bike.jpg?raw=1 instead. (Notice the `?raw=1`.) See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 to learn about shared links and how to convert them to links to direct links to the content.
2. Ask for a "direct link" from the Chooser instead of a "preview link" (the default). See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#js for details on how to set up the Chooser with different options. If you ask for a "direct link," you'll get a link directly to the file content.

#2 is probably the better option, since it doesn't have the side effect of sharing the file. (With a "preview link," the user will see that a new shared link has been created when they visit www.dropbox.com/links.)

Comment: I don't know. The `gdrive://` URL seems to come from a jQuery plugin called [`jquery-gdrive`](https://github.com/tanmaykm/jquery-gdrive). You may want to ask the author of that library?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the dropbox URL in a "inprivate" session or in a new browser that's not logged in to dropbox, you'll see that you get prompted to login to dropbox before you can access the image.

The web server (which runs the PHP-code), isn't logged in to dropbox and will most likely only get, and download, the login page and not the image.

The Google Drive URL isn't a valid URL since it starts with gdrive://. Your web server has no idea how to use that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruqu1bfrs371ntj/spokeless-bike.jpg?dl=1 which is used to download the file, just check with https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.